# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time for the site's first new cycle of Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- artistic blogs and websites
- useful resources and tutorials for designers of all skill levels
- examples of well-designed content
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 × 250 pixels** or doubled to **440 x 500** (per: [Do the double-size retina-screen community ads work on all sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247063/do-the-double-size-retina-screen-community-ads-work-on-all-sites))
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 kb

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1340).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Answer (score 15):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: This won't actually get hooked up through ads, one because you have text in the post, and also because it doesn't actually link to anything. I think the idea has some merit, but keep in mind, ads get shown to anonymous users as well as unregistered users, who can't vote, and in the case of the former, registering doesn't allow them to vote automatically either.

Comment: @GraceNote Ah, that's what that template was for. Honestly, I'd end up having it link to the site's home page. Imho, the fact that users who can't upvote see this as well, should just be an incentive to them to become elegible :)

Comment: Anonymoous downvoter, could you please clarify why you don't like this ad? It seems to me that voting is crucial on this site. Thanks!

Comment: First off, I didn't downvote it. However, I feel the promotion is a good idea but focused on the wrong action. The site overall isn't measured on upvotes, but it is measured on *accepted* answers. I would like to see something like this for accepting answers, but also pointing to a well written meta post about why it's important to accept answers, and maybe even including a few pointers on what to think about when accepting answers (future value, waiting a few days for a little bit of exposure and more answers, etc).

Comment: @Dom although the site isn't measured on upvotes, but the *user engagement* **is**. We sorely need more users with more reputation to keep improving on the site's quality. It turns out, for example, that only **37** users have the privilege to cast close votes. By upvoting more, we can ensure that number rises.

Comment: Questions need upvotes too.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft feel free to make an ad promoting that :D

Comment: @Vincent: I was rather thinking about tweaking this add not to be limited to answers.

Comment: @Dom Maybe you should make an accepted answer one. I definitely would support it myself. There is room for more then just one good habit encouragement!

Comment: @GiantCowFilms alone it wouldn't be very effective. It'd need a decent explanation to point to on meta which I just don't have the time to write. It wouldn't be too difficult to make the graphic bit though. I think similar to this just with the accepted answer symbol and some different writing.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Help build a 3D graphics knowledge base here on Stack Exchange!]

Comment: This could be very useful! There was a [**very recent question**](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/are-we-going-to-allow-3ds-max-questions-yes-or-no) that is related to this.

Comment: 3D graphics is a large and interesting field for all designers. Help us create a dedicated Q&A site

Answer (score 9):

[image: Chat with fellow site members]

Comment: [Here's](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2239676/Stack%20Exchange/Graphic%20Design/GD-Chat-Ad.ai) The .ai file should this ever need to be edited. Thanks to Matt, Zach, and Dom for assisting with the design

Comment: love the last point (+1)

Comment: Am I the only one that sees it off-center due to the last bullet?

Comment: @Dom I think it's fine as is.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Arts and Crafts Q&A]

Answer (score 4):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is an adaption of [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884).

Answer (score 4):

[image: Hardware Recommendations SE beta site]

Comment: It's not uncommon for use to get hardware recommendation questions that don't quite fit our scope ([recent example](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/61132/8708)), so I think this would be a good fit for our site.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Method of Action is a collection of tools, games and articles to help you learn design.]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Visit Typography.Guru]

Comment: This is not the correct size.

Comment: @Ryan: [Double size is okay.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247063/255554)

Comment: Ah okay. Good to know, I'll edit the instructions to include that.

Comment: I think Community Ads are currently disabled until the dust settles around the 300px switch. I widened [this one](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2540/8708) but after lots of refreshing on this site and others, I'm not seeing _any_ Community Ads anywhere. I suspect we'll just have to wait for the 2016 submission posts before we get to see wider Community Ads in action

Answer (score 2):

[image: Help the community and gain reputation points!]

Comment: Beginners might be interested to try to answer some questions and gain some privileges that will let them participate more to the community.

Comment: I would recommend that they get pointed to [the newest ones](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) because they are likely more easily answerable to newcomers

Comment: Seems like a good idea, I changed the url, thanks! I wish there was a way to sort them by newest + no answers at all, but maybe I'm overthinking it.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Ask a question. Get answers. Accept one!]

Comment: ^ posting here so I can use it in the comments later!

Comment: It has an angry and unfriendly tone to me

Answer (score -3):

[image: Join Wikivoyage and create banners]

Comment: This ad does not adhere to the guidelines.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Thanks for your feedback! What guideline in particular? Size? Topic? Cheers!

Comment: See the first post. At the very most the following rule is not met: “The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**”

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Double size is actually OK, it is designed for optimal rendering on Retina: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247063/do-the-double-size-retina-screen-community-ads-work-on-all-sites See also the "Bounties" ad which is double-size as well. Cheers!

Comment: +1 Some feedback: I think this should contain the wikivoyage logo, and have the text in the same font. Also, I'm not sure "Time for creativity!" is needed. Maybe "Help us create banners for collaborative travel guides!" is better...

Comment: @Earthliŋ: Great idea, I will add the logo as soon as I can! I fear replacing the text as you suggest might make the advertisement feel too much "advertising", don't you think so? I also want to stress that making banners is not just choosing a nice picture, it is a composition/color/illustration exercise in a very particular design format. Should I also state that Wikivoyage is not for profit, so it is not just a company willing to benefit from free workers?

Answer (score -4):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: I'm a very active member of this site, but I see no use following the twitter feed. It's just some questions I've already seen. If I see no use in it, why should we promote it?

Comment: I think the idea is, interesting questions get re-tweeted and reach people not yet aware of the site. It's there to be shared, not just followed