# Good places to send 3D users?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Recently the topicality of 3D questions has [come under discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/are-we-going-to-allow-3ds-max-questions-yes-or-no). The main issue here is that Graphic Design's user base is unable to answer or handle a good deal of these 3D questions. [I think the best solution moving forward would be to pass them off to different sites that are not part of the SE network](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2554/26236), since the [3D.SE proposal on Area 51 was closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics) during the early days of beta.
**What are some good, friendly 3d forums to send these users to?**

Comment: Kudos on coming up with this idea! Even if it's a temporary thing, it's good to know how we can at least try to help.

Comment: GiantCow has started a renewed Area 51 proposal, since the old one was rather, well, old already. You can follow it [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics-modeling-animation).

Answer (score 7):

## http://forums.cgsociety.org/

This is one of the largest 3D forums on the internet. I'm not sure how friendly it is, since I don't post there myself, however it is definitely well trafficked.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, cgtalk is the big one. Some additional ones include:

- http://forums.3dtotal.com/
- http://www.creativecrash.com/forums
- http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/Discussions-Page

Comment: How did I forget 3dtotal, I read posts there all the time, facepalm. cool to see the other ones

Comment: The precursor of creative crash used to be big, but cc its all but dead. In part because im not interested in answering stuff anymore.

Answer (score 3):

In my humble opinion, the best place to ask a 3D software related question is the software official forum, or the official un-oficcial :o).

I am not sure about the expensive packages like autodesk's, but that works on blender, sketchup, some render engines, etc.

http://blenderartists.org/forum/

http://sketchucation.com/forums/

Answer (score -1):

There really is no good place to send people for definite answers. The available contain a lot of noise, and its hard to separate noise from good answers.

So theres no good replacement for Stackexhange style sites. Worth remembering when making for a 3D stackexhange.

Comment: However, something is better then nothing, and until SE has a 3D site, we might at least give them *somewhere* to go

Comment: @GiantCowFilms not necceserily entirely true. Its good to know that the niche is different in anycase. I dont think we should recommend anything particular.