# What's the census on CAD and 3D for GD.SE?

Tags: discussion

There appear to be questions asked regularly on the topic but the community isn't voting to close them.  So are we going to allow them or not?  Either we need to close them and encourage the proposal on area51: "[3D Graphics, Modeling & Animation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics-modeling-animation)" or we need to open the questions we did close and allow them to be answered.

Which one does the community want?  The last discussion on this was in April, "[Are we going to allow 3DS Max/Maya/Modo… questions? YES or NO?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/are-we-going-to-allow-3ds-max-maya-modo-questions-yes-or-no)".

I was under the impression the community felt we should close and send them to the proposal but has this changed?

Comment: The last discussion was not in April. http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/why-is-this-site-called-graphic-design-when-it-doesnt-include-3d-questions

Comment: Ok then it was in august.  Still.  We dont have a definitive yes or no and swapping back and forth is just going to discourage new users.

Comment: I feel like a part of it is that we don't have that many users who *can* vote to close and even fewer of those are active daily to do so

Answer (score 9):

For what it's worth, I would say no. I think for 3d to be dealt with comprehensively, it deserves its own stack, and the more we divert to the Area51 proposal, the better.

In fact, if I had my wicked way, I would ban a lot of tech support questions from the graphic design stack, in favour of questions of design principles! Though this would be a bit extreme! :)

If I need advice on 3d, it's because the final 3d product will likely be rendered as a graphical image for design use. It's like the Arts and Crafts stack in Area 51 at the minute: I will not ask the Graphic Design stack about what type of craft tools I should use for illustration, as it's more specific to a process rather than a design solution. Yes, it serves as a *medium* for answering a graphic design problem, but the medium itself is where the question lies. Also I think 3d is such a huge area, that it deserves its own stack to be addressed properly, in spite of it not being supported enough in Area 51.

Comment: Defining "design" is tricky though... Typography is design, animated typography is design, layout is design, creating an animation in 3D to include it in a promotional newsletter or on a website is design, game design is design...

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but this is a graphic design stack. However! Let's say you're unsure of how to present a graphical presentation of a 3D cad plan for a prospective client. The images in this presentation may have been constructed with 3d software. But the only questions I can foresee as being relevant to a Graphic Design stack are questions of communication and representation of the design... Anything related to the actual 3d process/workflow isn't relevant. You can apply graphic design principles to 3d design but the 3d process is too large to cover in this stack.

Comment: @fabriced Design is much bigger than graphic design, which deals with graphic communication and presentation. It is decidedly not the same as engineering design, mechanical design, furniture design, architecture or idustrial design. So drafting is off the scope, in general but could be depending on the question. DESIGN comes in different flavours and graphics design is a small niche in overall design categorisation. In fact one of the least broad of the niches in fact. So no, you dont have exclusive rights to all of the design world.

Comment: Restricting one's skills doesn't make them better at what they do... If design is graphical, it is graphic design... "Illustration" and "typography" are tags on GD SE, and you can use 3d to make illustrations or typography!

Comment: I find quite illogical to restrict the scope of communities; there actually is a 3D SE community, but restricted to Blender. Everything is allowed there, even design or typography, if done with Blender, while GD S.E. discourages to ask how to use PS or AI (etc) in particular, saying tutorials can be found elsewhere (but allows font identification Qs, although this exists elsewhere as well). Kind of hard to rationalise that these two communities coexist on S.E.... For some strange reason I find the blender S.E to be much more useful

Answer (score 6):

No,

seriously. Nothing short of whats allowed now. I am still against this.

Do we really need to have this discussion over and over again. I mean if we do then i will start nagging on some aspect that we allow and keep nagging until you decide its not allowed. If you want it, say so.

There is no point in trying to be something you are not just because of fun. There has to be some borders on questions. Even arbitrary ones.

Answer (score 6):

Unless the CAD or 3D design work is being used for an actual graphic design project and the asked question actually relates to "design" (as opposed to how to use a 3D program), I think they should be closed as they don't fit the aims and objectives of this exchange.